# cannot insert into the MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have several xml files. I am trying to insert the data collected from those xml files into a database. The problem is that some got inserted and some other ones are not. here are two of the xml files. The first one is inserted without any pb, however, the second one is not inserted into the data base.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<recipeml version="0.5">
  <recipe>
    <head>
      <title>10 Minute Meat Loaf</title>
      <categories>
        <cat>Beef</cat></categories>
      <yield>4</yield></head>
    <ingredients>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1</qty>
          <unit>pound</unit></amt>
        <item>Ground beef</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1</qty>
          <unit/></amt>
        <item>Egg</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1/2</qty>
          <unit>cups</unit></amt>
        <item>Bread crumbs</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1/4</qty>
          <unit>cups</unit></amt>
        <item>Milk</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>2</qty>
          <unit>tablespoons</unit></amt>
        <item>Onion soup mix</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>2</qty>
          <unit>tablespoons</unit></amt>
        <item>Ketchup</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>2</qty>
          <unit>tablespoons</unit></amt>
        <item>Soy sauce</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1/2</qty>
          <unit>cups</unit></amt>
        <item>Swiss cheese; shredded</item></ing></ingredients>
    <directions>
      <step>  Combine all ingredients and shape into a round or oval loaf. Place in
  microwave-safe dish, cover with waxed paper and microwave on high for 10
  minutes, turning dish after 5 minutes, of cooking, drain and cover with
  foil. Let stand 10 minutes before slicing. Makes 4-6 servings.

  busted by sooz

  Recipe by: Key Gourmet

  Posted to recipelu-digest by sooz &lt;kirkland@gj.net&gt; on Mar 18, 1998

</step></directions></recipe></recipeml>
```

*******second XML File I have trouble to insert into the database**********

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<recipeml version="0.5">
  <recipe>
    <head>
      <title>10 Can Chicken Casserole</title>
      <categories>
        <cat>Casserole</cat></categories>
      <yield>8</yield></head>
    <ingredients>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1</qty>
          <unit>large</unit></amt>
        <item>Fryer; boiled with onion and celery; deboned, cut up</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1</qty>
          <unit>can</unit></amt>
        <item>Cheddar cheese soup</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1</qty>
          <unit>can</unit></amt>
        <item>Cream of mushroom soup</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1</qty>
          <unit>can</unit></amt>
        <item>(small) evaporated milk</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1</qty>
          <unit>can</unit></amt>
        <item>(#202) asparagus tips; drained</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1</qty>
          <unit>can</unit></amt>
        <item>French style green beans; drained</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1</qty>
          <unit>can</unit></amt>
        <item>Water chestnuts; drained, sliced</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1</qty>
          <unit>can</unit></amt>
        <item>(4-oz) mushroom stems &amp; pieces with liquid</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1</qty>
          <unit>can</unit></amt>
        <item>(small) pimento; diced, with liquid</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1</qty>
          <unit>can</unit></amt>
        <item>Chow mein noodles</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1</qty>
          <unit>can</unit></amt>
        <item>French fried onion rings</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty/>
          <unit/></amt>
        <item>Red pepper to taste</item></ing></ingredients>
    <directions>
      <step>   Mix all ingredients, except the onion rings, together. Put into a 3 quart
  casserole; top with onion rings. Bake at 350 degrees until bubbly,
  approximately 30 minutes.

  From &lt;A Taste of Louisiana&gt;.Downloaded from Glen's MM Recipe Archive,
  http://www.erols.com/hosey.

</step></directions></recipe></recipeml>
```

now, this is my code in php5:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'recipe');
                        if (!$link) 
                        {
                            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                        }

                                    mysql_select_db('php_database');

                                $sql = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `recipe`';
                                    mysql_query( $sql, $link );

                                    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE `recipe` (
                                            `idRecipe` TINYINT( 12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
                                            `RecipeTitle` VARCHAR( 75 ) NOT NULL,
                                            `Yield` TINYINT( 5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
                                            `Steps` Text( 10000 ) NOT NULL,

                                            PRIMARY KEY ( `idRecipe` )
                                            )';
                                    echo 'Creating table: \'recipe\'....';
                                    mysql_query( $sql, $link );



        if ($handle = opendir('C:\wamp\www\PhP\Folder xml'))
        {   


            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
            {   //$i++;

                    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
                    {



                        if (file_exists($file))
                        {   

                            $use_errors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
                            $xml = simplexml_load_file($file); 
                            if (!$xml)
                            {
                                echo ("Cannot open the XML file $file <br />");

                            }
                            else
                            {

                                echo "<br /> <br />";

                                $title=$xml->recipe->head->title;
                                $yield=$xml->recipe->head->yield;
                                $step=$xml->recipe->directions->step;

                                echo "value of Recipe Title= $title, yield= $yield and step= $step<b />";
                                mysql_query("INSERT INTO recipe (RecipeTitle,Yield,Steps) values ('$title', '$yield','$step')");
                                 printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
                                mysql_close($link);
                                echo "<br />";

                                $xmla= "$file";
                                $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
                                $xmlDoc->load($xmla);
                                $cat = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("cat");
                                $numOfcat = $cat->length;
                                echo "@@ here is the number of cat  :$numOfcat  @@<br />";

                                $qty = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("qty");
                                $numOfqty = $qty->length;
                                echo "@@ here is the number of qty  :$numOfqty  @@<br />";


                                echo $xml->getName() . "<br />"; // displays recipeml

                                foreach($xml->children() as $child) 
                                {
                                    echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />"; //displays recipe:
                                    //echo "INSERT " . $child . " INTO....";

                                    echo ("title=  ");
                                    echo $xml->recipe->head->title .  " ,\r\n" ; //displays the title
                                    echo ("category= ");
                                    echo $xml->recipe->head->categories->cat . ",\n" ;// displays the category
                                    echo ("yield= ");
                                    echo $xml->recipe->head->yield . ",\n" ; //displays yield number
                                    echo ("quantity= ");
                                    echo $xml->recipe->ingredients->ing->amt->qty . ",\n" ; //displays quantity
                                    echo ("unit= ");
                                    echo $xml->recipe->ingredients->ing->amt->unit . ",\n" ; ////displays unit
                                    echo ("Item= ");
                                    echo $xml->recipe->ingredients->ing->item . ",\n" ; //displays item

                                        for($i=1; $i<$numOfqty; $i=$i+1)
                                        {
                                            echo ("quantity= ");
                                            echo $xml->recipe->ingredients->ing[$i]->amt->qty . ",\n" ;
                                            echo ("unit= ");
                                            echo $xml->recipe->ingredients->ing[$i]->amt->unit . ",\n" ;
                                            echo ("Item= ");
                                            echo $xml->recipe->ingredients->ing[$i]->item . ",\n" ; 
                                        } 
                                    echo ("Step to cook=********************** ");  
                                    echo $xml->recipe->directions->step . ",\n" ; //displays item 
                                }
                            }
                        }   
                    }    
            }  
        }

        closedir($handle);
?>
```

Any suggestions? many of those files are not well formed, But I used Altova to check if those two xml files are well formed and altova confirmed that they are both well formed.  I will appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks,

T3000.

Comment: XML in database, can't be good.

Comment: Please define your problem better. What's happening when it's not working?

Comment: @Connor - Not necessarily disagreeing, but why is XML a problem in INSERTs?

Comment: Instead of `mysql_query("INSERT INTO ...")`, you can try: `$query="INSERT INTO ..."; echo($query); mysql_query($query) or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());` to catch the error if it from a malformed MySQL query.

Answer (score 4):

You have a ' in your second directions->step, which will make the query fail, as the rest of the text after the ' will be seen as regular SQL - which it is not.

You should use [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on the strings before inserting them to the query.

Or switch to [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or a DB abstraction layer that utilizes prepared statements.

Comment: I used mysql_real_escape_string and it works for the one that did not work earlier. However, when I added the two files in the folder, the code does not work fine anymore. I get the message: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\wamp\www\PhP\Folder xml\test.php on line 59.

Comment: Try adding your db-link object/variable `$link` as a second parameter to the function. And i can see you use `$link` with your other mysql_ functions, so maybe you should add it to the `mysql_insert_id()` you are using in your code.

Comment: I see your problem.. you `mysql_close()` the connection right after your first insert. Don't do that in your `while()` statement, the next loop will have no db connection, thus not insert!

Comment: I used mysql_real_escape_string, and I got rid of mysql_close(). Now, it works fine . i can insert data from the two xml files. Thanks for your help Phliplip, and thanks to all of you for your suggestions.

Comment: You're welcome :) Note that it's usually not a requirement to add the $link parameter - thus it is optional ;)

Comment: ok, now i got it. I have another problem. what is the maximum of file that I can have in the same folder (wamp) and be able to read, extract and populate the database? Because I have 1500 files in the wamp server folder, but for some reasons, i can insert only up to 255 records (each record=xml file). any suggestions?  thanks

Comment: This is because you have used TINYINT for fieldtype on the idRecipe field. Use MEDIUMINT(1) instead. [Bookmark this link](http://www.hockinson.com/index.php?s=36) it's a good reference for field types. Unlike varchar the number in the paranthesis don't dictate lenght. An unsigned MEDIUMINT(1) will give you room for 16,777,217 records.

Comment: out of 1500, I had inserted 1472 records into the database. Thaks again Phliplip. You helped me a lot!

Comment: This is because you have used TINYINT for fieldtype on the idRecipe field. Use MEDIUMINT(1) instead. [Bookmark this link](http://www.hockinson.com/index.php?s=36) it's a good reference for field types. An unsigned MEDIUMINT(1) will give you room for 16,777,217 records. Unlike varchar the number in the paranthesis don't dictate lenght. It's used in conjunction with the ZEROFILL keyword, if the field has MEDIUMINT(6) and the inserted integer is 353, the data is filled with zeros for the rest, the result would be 000353. This last bit i have never tried, but thats how i have understood the theory

Comment: Now, I am trying to insert about 21,000 records. But the browsers freezes, and nothing inside the database. What can be the problem? thanks again for your time.

Comment: Well.. loads of things actually. Faulty SQL query perhaps, are you using `mysql_query() or die(mysql_error());` ? This would give you an error message if it's the SQL that fails. Else it's back to basic debugging, try inserting `die('works fine here');` somewhere in your script. If the text **works fine here** shows in the browser then try moving it down som lines, if not move it up. You should start from the top. This way you will likely figure out what section of your code is faulty. Also, if the browser don't show anything, then you could have a timeout problem, is the page loading 30 secs?

Comment: And also try looking in your logs, and remember to turn on error_reporting and display_errors.

Answer (score 2):

mysql_real_escape_string() will escape your data & using or die will report where its failed. basic debugging...

```
$query="INSERT INTO recipe (RecipeTitle,Yield,Steps) values
                        ('".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."',
                         '".mysql_real_escape_string($yield)."',
                         '".mysql_real_escape_string($step)."')";
mysql_query($query,$link) or die(mysql_error());
```

You close your connection after the first iteration and then link is not established again.

> Using mysql_close() isn't usually
>   necessary, as non-persistent open
>   links are automatically closed at the
>   end of the script's execution.

Unrelated but Use a url friendly path, underscores instead of spaces

```
$handle = opendir('C:\wamp\www\PhP\Folder_xml');
```

Comment: He should probably actually use `opendir($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/PhP/Folder_xml")` as it will make the code more portable. Ad@m